# How I make FluentValidation show nested properties as camelCase not PascalCase in .Net web api?

Tags: .net, fluentvalidation, modelstate

**camelCase in Fluent validation in .Net 6 Web Api**

Nested properties are *PascalCase* from Fluent Validation, how can i change it to be *camelCase* for nested objects/everything?

For the client I use React, I do not want to convert it client-side.

What i currently have is:

```json
{
    "name": [
        "Navn på vin er påkrevd.",
        "Navn på vin må minst være 3 bokstaver."
    ],
    "type": [
        "Type er påkrevd."
    ],
    // What i want: userDetails.quantity
    "userDetails.Quantity": [
        "'user Details Quantity' must be between 0 and 2000. You entered -1."
    ]
}
```

[validation response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hi8TY.png)

What i want is *userDetails.quantity* not *userDetails.Quantity*

I have this in my Program.cs class

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddFluentValidation(fv =>
    {
        fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<AddWineValidator>();
    })
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would suggest using fluentvalidation's PropertyNameResolver for the job.
I think this [issue on github](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/226) directly answers your question.

Comment: It would help to apply code from the github to show how to solve the question.